# ruby error when upgrading ruby from 1.8 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

I want to upgrade ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3, using  rvm install.

Upgrading to support "puppetlabs_spec_helper" since this will only if ruby 1.9.3 present.

Getting below error when installing

```
]# rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p551
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/6/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/CVE-2015-1855-p484.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring.............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling...................................................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #installing........................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #making binaries executable..
curl: (28) connect() timed out!
There was an error while trying to resolve rubygems version for 'latest'.
Halting the installation.
```

I enabled proxy  by "export http_proxy"

I am also confused with below command

```
 ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

]# /opt/puppet/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

how its showing different version.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have two doubts 1) how to recover the "timeout error" when upgrade ruby and 2) why "/opt/puppet/bin/ruby" showing version 1.9.3 when installation not completed.

Comment: Why do you want to use RVM, if I may ask? Why not just recompile ruby from source? Also why are you installing an outdated/unsupported version? I am just wondering

Comment: I am writing rspec-puppet test case wanna include "puppetlabs_spec_helper", this gem doesn't support ruby 1.8 so I am going to upgrade ruby to 1.9.3, I surfed net for ruby upgrade and got an update need install by rvm

Comment: Can someone please help me on this. I am breaking my head more that 2 days.

Comment: @Puppeteer If you no longer need 1.8, I would suggest uninstalling rvm and running a different manager: rbenv. I can help you out if needed. (Just tag my name)

Comment: thanks for your help I installed ruby 1.9 via rvm